# Import data from a txt file in a MySQL database with PHP on visit

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using PHPMyAdmin to run my MySQL database.

Suppose we have this txt file "people.txt", a MySQL database and a PHP page in which are showed the data from the database. Suppose that data in the text file are stored with this syntax:

```
2015/16/01|Alex|Paris  
2015/13/01|Johnny|Berlin  
2015/11/01|Mary|Oslo
```

You can notice that each field is separated with a |

Is there any way to import these data using a PHP script? I want to show you a different script that, when the page is visited, send data to the database:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "my_db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO `People` (data, name, city)
VALUES ('2015/10/01', 'Will', 'Rome')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
    echo "OK!";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

I want to emulate this script in order to let check, each time the page is visited, the txt file. Any help?

---

I tried to merge the PHP script that shows my data and the one that import them from the txt file but it doesn't seem to work properly..

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = "
    LOAD DATA INFILE 'people.txt'
    INTO TABLE `People`
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
";

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `People`");

echo "<table class='people'>
<tr class='titles'>
<th>Data</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>City</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Data'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['City'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the ["LOAD DATA INFILE"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html) statement to just load the data into the table every time the page is visited.

```
$sql = "
    LOAD DATA INFILE 'people.txt'
    INTO TABLE `People`
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
";
```

One part of the SQL to look into are the `REPLACE` or `IGNORE` option, which determines what will happen if the script tries to insert a row that duplicate an existing unique key, if your table has any.

Also, if your input file has fields in a different order than your database table, then you can provide a list of columns at the end of the SQL, like `(data, name, city)`.

Other than those things, I think you should simply be able to replace the `$sql` variable in your posted code with something like the above SQL, then run (as in your original code):

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "OK!";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: Good point, but I forget to mention that I'm a newbe in PHP and Mysql. I need more instruction to accomplish your suggestion!

Comment: Please, have a look at my question. I edited it adding more information about what is happening with my database..

Comment: well, I have no feedback.. blank page.. except for the initial table with the main information as Date, Name and City..

Comment: Sorry, hard to help...can you check your server logs, or PHP logs, to see if there is an exception? If you have something like MySQL Workbench, you can try the SQL directly against the table. That way you can get the syntax of the LOAD DATA statement exactly correct before running the PHP script.

Comment: I can use Phpmyadmin in order to try the SQL but, if I do not know very well PHP, for SQL the situation is even worse.. Anyway, we can try that way

Comment: I tried to imagine the cause of the error of the script that I made with your help.. Maybe I have to specify in a better way the path of the file! Or maybe the script imported it but the database didn't know how to read it.. Maybe I have to specify a particular syntax in the script in order to make the database read it well

Comment: The file path is definitely a good idea for what the problem is. Trying it in PHPMyAdmin is also a good idea. There should be some errors in the logs if you are just getting a blank screen.