# How can i reduce my text file size?

Tags: php, mysql, text-files

I have a php code that gets product IDs from my database (23436 unique records).

I fetch each product ID and check if it has been set in feature_product table by comparing productIDs.

If no records are found under that ID in features tables than I get check a trial.txt file for the missing features of the products again by comparing the productID in the text file with the productID that was not present in the feature_product table.

The problem is the trial.txt file has 593262 lines in it and it takes forever to match productID in this file. I run out of memory. I took me 15 hours to actually get all the data off the file and that too in parts manually. Is there any way to make it faster or not run out of time and memory?

I tried increasing the max execution time in my php.ini file as suggested by some posts on sites. But it keeps running out of memory or max execution time. I will be using mysqli once i get this right, as mysql is not used any more. I thought of dividing the product IDs so i can loop only say 5000 at a time but I don't think it would help in execution time.

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "dbuser", "pwd");  

 //loop through the 1st line to avoid the headers in csv
 if (!$conn){ 
 die('Could not connect : ' . mysql_error()); 
 echo mysql_error();
 }  
 echo '<p>Connected!';

 mysql_select_db("mydb") or die( "Unable to select database");

//Select all product ids from product table into product array
 $pArray = mysql_query("SELECT `id_product` from `product`",$conn);

 //loop through each product id
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($pArray)) {

 //get product ID to check if it exists in features table
 $productID = $row["id_product"];

//check whether product id exists in feature table where product_id matches both product table and features table
 $fArray = mysql_query("SELECT * from `feature_product` WHERE `id_product`=$productID");

//if product Id does not have entry in feature table than call a function to get check if product id has features in text file
if(mysql_num_rows($fArray) ==0)
 {
 checkFeatures($productID);
 }
 else continue;
}

function checkFeatures($productID){
//trial.txt contains features of the products that are missing in features table but the products are in products table
$fd = fopen('trial.txt', 'r');
$fheader = fgets($fd); 

//creates a new text file to save all features(multiple records per product) separated by ',' for future use
$my_file = 'file.txt';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'a') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);

while (($data = fgetcsv($fd,0, "~")) !== FALSE) {
//Since this text file has many products i only get the ones that are missing in the features table by comparing product ID which is the 1st element of data array
     if($data[0]==$productID){
     $d= $data[0].",".$data[1].",".$data[2].$data[3]."\n";
     echo $d."<BR/>";
     fwrite($handle, $d);
     }  
}
fclose($fd);
fclose($handle);

   }
?>
```

example of **product table**

```
id_product,shop,manufacutrer,category  
1000010,1,41,1112,1  
1000011,1,7,1721,1  
1000012,1,7,1721,1
```

example of **feature table**

```
feature_id,id_product,value  
1,1000010,1  
3,1000010,2  
6,1000011,5  
11,1931555,1
```

sample **trial.txt**

```
IMSKU~AttributeID~Value~Unit~StoredValue~StoredUnit  
1000006~16121~2-25~~~  
1000006~3897~* McAfee Protection Suite~~~  
1000006~3933~* 1yr Subscription~~~  
1000010~1708~Feb 2011~~~  
1000010~1710~Cisco~~0.00~  
1000010~1711~http://www.cisco.com~~~  
1000011~2852~1~~0.00~  
1000011~2855~Light Cyan~~0.00~  
1000012~2840~May 2010~~~  
1000012~2842~HP~~0.00~
```

I tried to load the text file as a table in sql as suggested by the users

```
<?php  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","pwd","db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_query($con,"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `add_features` (`id_product` INT(10) NOT NULL, `id_feature` INT(10) NOT NULL, `value` varchar(255),`unit` varchar(20),`s_value` varchar(20),`s_unit` varchar(20))");

$sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE 'trial.txt'
INTO TABLE `add_features`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '~'
";
if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "OK!";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
} 
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `add_features`");

echo "<table class='add_features'>
<tr class='titles'>
<th>Product_id</th>
<th>feature_id</th>
<th>value</th>
<th>Unit</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['id_product'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['id_feature'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['value'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['unit'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

But i am getting an error
    Error: LOAD DATA INFILE 'trial.txt' INTO TABLE `add_features` FIELDS TERMINATED BY '~'

Comment: iport the text file in to a db

Comment: @Dagon I have edited my code to show load the text file into db. I have never done it before but i am getting this error.

Comment: The error message you have shown is likely incomplete, is there more? I have used your code and it imported correctly and displayed the data. You should add `IGNORE 1 LINES` to your LOAD DATA query to skip the header row with the field names. Is the data file in your mysql data directory?

Comment: I did like you said and ignored the 1st line. It is working for me now.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Remember to add indexes to your `add_features` table for quick access.

Comment: That was a good tip, i would have missed it i you had not mentioned it. I had another error, in my text file there are product descriptions which have the sql Keywords Max and Min in many lines. The table stops copying from there onwards and shows errors.Does this happen often while copying data into sql table? I don't know what to do with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the trial.txt file is static, I would process it / parse it into either separate smaller files based on some logical divider, or import it into a new database table (preferable) where searching it will be instant. It's a one time import and then it's done.

If it's not static, how often does it change?

Comment: The text file does not change very often. Only when new products are added. Which may happen once a month or once two months. So insert the text file in database as a table would be a better option. I need to redo the whole code it seems as this one will definitely run out of time.

Comment: Yes, definitely import it into the database. Writing code to import and then search the new table will be trivial and save you tons of frustration and hours of processing time.

Comment: Ok I am going to give a go and soon post my result.

Comment: I am getting an error while i try to load the text file into sql db.         Error: LOAD DATA INFILE 'trial.txt' INTO TABLE `add_features` FIELDS TERMINATED BY '~' 

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in ../features.php on line 28 .  I am not sure but do i need  to create the table first or does 'LOAD' create one for me? As the examples i see online they do not show how to create a table. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27975228/import-data-from-a-txt-file-in-a-mysql-database-with-php-on-visit

Comment: You need to create the table first to match your file definition. What database (mySQL?) and what front end (phpMyAdmin?) are you using? You'll have to google how to create the table you want with the front end you have if you haven't created tables before. You can also create your tables using php, but I would suggest using a front end like phpMyAdmin.

Comment: I'm using mysql and front end is phpMyAdmin. I edited the code to create table. It is creating the table correctly but not adding any data in the table.

Comment: If you post the table structure, I can help troubleshoot. If you are using the Import tab, what settings are you entering: e.g. Format: csv Columns separated with: ~ etc... If you are using the SQL tab, what command are your using?